# Duplicate Tags From Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, tags

If i have an Array in JS:

```
var myArray = [ 'text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3'];
```

How i can duplicate and DIV tag and Set all the array values?, Like This:

```
<div>text 1</div>
<div>text 1</div>
<div>text 1</div>
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var divBlocks = myArray.map(function(x) { return "<div>" + x + "</div>"; });
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that map is not supported in certain browsers and must be shimmed for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var key in myArray)
{
    createDiv(key);
}
```

Reference: [JavaScript For...In Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp)

Comment: I would argue that the for in state is more useful for object property iteration and that using the more commonly supported forloop or simply the new forEach operator would be better when dealing with an array.